# Why is replaceCurrentItem so slow on AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, audio-streaming, avplayeritem

I'm developing a music app and I need to often swap between streaming urls. My current implementation includes an `AVPlayer` and a `PlayerItem` who are defined as global variables in my manager:

```
public var player: AVPlayer?
public var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
```

Every time the user taps a content, I change the player item and play the new one:

```
public func changePlayerItem(withUrl url: URL) {
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    ...
```

However the execution of the `replaceCurrentItem` function creates a noticeable delay of a couple of seconds. This delay is reduced to zero if I do the following instead:

```
 public func changePlayerItem(withUrl url: URL) {
    player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    ...
```

If I define `playerItem` as a local variable instead:

```
 public func changePlayerItem(withUrl url: URL) {
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    ...
```

It seems there is no delay in this case, but I hear no audio.

MacOS Big Sur 11.6, Xcode 13.1. Deployment target is iOS 13.0 and I'm testing on iPhone 7plus with iOS 15.0.2.

Why is this happening? Is there a reason behind it?

Comment: I'm not super knowledgeable about AVPlayer, but I have been using the Internet since before it was called the Internet... Could it be buffering the stream during the delay?

Comment: @ScottThompson I mean yes, it could, but why if I instantiate AVPlayer again instead this delay doesn't occur?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know.  Unless it's waiting for the existing buffer to be free so it can start bringing in new content.  But that's just a wild guess.